# CSS - how to set a position of UL in LI

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have following a HTML structure of list that contains another list:

```
<ul>
 <li>a</li>

 <li>b
  <ul>
   <li>b-a</li>
   <li>b-b</li>
   <li>b-c</li>
  </ul>
 </li>

 <li>c
  <ul>
   <li>c-a</li>
   <li>c-b</li>
  </ul>
 </li>

 <li>d</li>
</ul>
```

The inner **UL** are hidden and after **mouseover** they are set as visible. My problem consists in if I will move the cursor on **LI** item that contains inner **UL**, so this inner **UL** is displayed, but in the begin line, not exactly under **LI** item (in this case under **LI** with the words **b** and **c**).

Can you help me, please, how to set the inner **UL** exactly under the words, that contains inner **UL** lists?

thank you so much

Comment: please paste your code on jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Checkout this tutorial http://www.seoconsultants.com/css/menus/tutorial/

try this for jquery http://www.noupe.com/tutorial/drop-down-menu-jquery-css.html